ggplot2 error: 'object 'days_after_grounding' not found' when building plot, despite column existing in dataset
Apologies for any mistakes, I'm new to R. I'm trying to create an animated plot using ggplot2 and plotly in R, but I'm encountering an error that I can't resolve. Here's my code:
ggplot(overall_grounded_mapping,aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=flight_count, color = flight_count, frame=days_after_grounding))+
  geom_polygon(data=state, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group), fill="lightgray", color ="white", size = 0.1)+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE)+
  scale_color_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")+ 
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.5, 7.5))+
  labs(title = "Flights by Destination")+
  theme_void()+
  coord_quickmap()

It results in
"Error in `geom_polygon()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error:
! object 'days_after_grounding' not found"

days_after_grounding exists in my dataset, here's a sample of it.
dataset
I ran:
dput(head(overall_grounded_mapping))

and it resulted in:
structure(list(days_after_grounding = c(-14, -14, -14, -14, -14, 
-14), dest = c("ABE", "ABQ", "AGS", "ALB", "AMA", "ATL"), lat = c(40.652099609375, 
35.040199, 33.3698997497559, 42.7482986450195, 35.219398, 33.6367
), lon = c(-75.440803527832, -106.609001, -81.9645004272461, 
-73.8016967773438, -101.706001, -84.428101), flight_count = c(1L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 22L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Running:
dput(head(state))

results in:
structure(list(long = c(-87.4620056152344, -87.4849319458008, 
-87.525032043457, -87.53076171875, -87.5708694458008, -87.5880584716797
), lat = c(30.3896808624268, 30.3724918365479, 30.3724918365479, 
30.3323860168457, 30.3266544342041, 30.3266544342041), group = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), order = 1:6, region = c("alabama", "alabama", 
"alabama", "alabama", "alabama", "alabama"), subregion = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

I'm trying to have each days_after_grounding be assigned to a specific frame in my animation. For example, all of the -14 points on one frame, all of the -13 points on another, etc. Thanks!

When you specify variable mappings in the ggplot(aes(...)) part, those are globally applied to all layers, unless you specify otherwise by specifying others and/or using inherit.aes = FALSE. You'll get an error if any of the layers' data sources are missing globally specified variables.
